# reduce array of objects: limit similar fields based on value from another field

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, sorting, npm

I need a fast way to perform this. It has to be fast.

In the array, the objects are sorted by score already. I want to make a new array with the top 2 scored objects for any given rootTerm.

Here is the original.

```
"results": [
        {
            "score": 100,
            "source": {
                "term": "bovine1",
                "rootTerm": "cow",
            }
        },
        {
            "score": 50,
            "source": {
                "term": "bovine2",
                "rootTerm": "cow",
            }
        },
        {
            "score": 10,
            "source": {
                "term": "bovine3",
                "rootTerm": "cow",
            }
        },
        {
            "score": 10,
            "source": {
                "term": "scrofa",
                "rootTerm": "pig",
            }
]
```

Bovine3 is not in the top 2 highest scored objects for rootTerm cow, so I want it removed.

The new result would be

```
"results": [
        {
            "score": 100,
            "source": {
                "term": "bovine1",
                "rootTerm": "cow",
            }
        },
        {
            "score": 50,
            "source": {
                "term": "bovine2",
                "rootTerm": "cow",
            }
        },
        {
            "score": 10,
            "source": {
                "term": "scrofa",
                "rootTerm": "pig",
            }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can filter it in place using `Array.filter()`, but you do need to track the rootTerms as you see them, keeping count as you go along.

```
var tracker = {};
data.filter(function(value, index, array) {
  var rootTerm = value.source.rootTerm;
  if (undefined === tracker[rootTerm])
  {
    tracker[rootTerm] = 0;
  }
  tracker[rootTerm] += 1;
  return (tracker[rootTerm] <= 2)
});
```

Comment: confused how to use this

Comment: Thanks that works. but to go get my results filtered, I have to go back through the tracker and check which ones were true. Can I multiply arrays in javascript??

Comment: filteredHits = []
for (var i = 0; i< hits.length; i++) {
    if (trackerBoolean[i]) {
        filteredHits.push(hits[i])
    }
}

Answer (score 0):

Make another array, with keys `cow`, `pig`, etc. and set values to 0. Iterate the original array and increase the value in second array every time you pass through entity with given key. Delete the entity if the value is 2 or more.

Example:

```
var counter = [pig: 0, cow: 0];
foreach(var key in originalArray) {
    if(++counter[originalArray[key].source.rootTerm] >= 2) {
        // remove somehow the item (maybe using array.splice() )... its on you
    }
}
```